# Attempting to format json data with PHP to use with Polymaps

Tags: php, json

Okay I'm attempting to use php to encode a json file I'm subsequently using to draw a map with the Polymaps service.

I'm having trouble when encoding my json from the Instagram API -- I'm able to do it, but I need the structure to be nested in this certain way. My code I have now encodes it in this format:

```
[
 {
  "title":"some value",
  "src":"some value",
  "lat":"some value",
  "lon":"some value"
},
...
```

So on and so forth. I need the format to match something more like this:

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[

  {
     "type":"Feature",
     "geometry":{
        "coordinates":[
           -94.34885,
           39.35757
        ],
        "type":"Point"
     },
     "properties":{
        "latitude":39.35757,
        "title":"Kearney",
        "id":919,
        "description":"I REALLY need new #converse, lol. I've had these for three years. So #destroyed ! :( Oh well. Can't wait to get a new pair and put my #rainbow laces through. #gay #gaypride #bi #proud #pride #colors #shoes #allstar #supporting ",
        "longitude":-94.34885,
        "user":"trena1echo5",
        "image":"http://images.instagram.com/media/2011/09/09/ddeb9bb508c94f2b8ff848a2d2cd3ece_7.jpg",
        "instagram_id":211443415
     }
  },
  {
     "type":"Feature",
     "geometry":{
        "coordinates":[
           -0.09402781,
           51.51512
        ],
        "type":"Point"
     },
     "properties":{
        "latitude":51.51512,
        "title":"City Of London",
        "id":918,
        "description":"#destroyed",
        "longitude":-0.09402781,
        "user":"axxoul",
        "image":"http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/09/09/ffda47fb97924a41bc36b0b024fcdfad_7.jpg",
        "instagram_id":211074717
     }
  },
```

...with its nested structure. I have the jquery working to read from the json file and the php script written to make the json...this is the last puzzle piece for me.

Comment: `"attempting to use php to encode a json file"` - have you tried using  [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Comment: Is it not possible to decode it into a php array, manipulate it into the format you need and then encode it back?

Comment: @Lix That makes sense. I'll try working with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to manipulate your JSON data with PHP, you could always use PHP's [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to convert your JSON into a PHP array.

Once you have your data in an easier format to deal with, you can make all the changes you require to the data using PHP's [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and once you are done you can encode it back to a JSON with PHP's [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!